# Asking for the solution for accessing the folder outside httpdocs

Tags: centos, apache-2.2

I had read one of one of your post that you were getting problem in accessing a folder outside httpdocs,The same problem I am getting I had done the safe mode off but than also it is not working,how you had fixed it? please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a folder, giving rights on it for your apache user (i suppose you're using apache), probably www-data or www and adding it to your apache config.

Here is an example configuration snippet allowing the listing of files in the folder 
/usr/local/outofdocroot/ (generates an index of your directory):

```
<Directory /usr/local/outofdocroot/>
Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

Add this to your apache2.conf/httpd.conf make sure the apache user can read the folder, and you should be serving that folder through apache without problem.

Comment: actually i am having 2 domains and in a file in domain1.com I am writing the function  chdir('/var/www/vhosts/domain2.com/httpdocs'); but it is not working,I have to access the files placed in domain2/httpdocs,how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you check that you have declared you're using Virtualhost in your apache config ? Running "apache2ctl -S" should give you something like: "*:80 is a NameVirtualHost"

Comment: Sorry,I am not getting it clearly but I had declare the virtual host in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file for both of the domains writing <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/httpdocs
    php_admin_flag safe_mode Off
    ServerName www.lykkel.dk
    ServerAlias lykkel.dk
    php_value include_path ".:/var/www/vhosts/domain2.com/httpdocs"
    DirectoryIndex index.php    
    
</VirtualHost>
 and than restarted the http service back